# sorting of 2d arrays in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

i'm a beginner in c. and a little bit confused about 2-d arrays which was pretty easy in python. let's suppose i declare an array[100][2] and take their readings. then i want to sort the elements through one dimension only. if i couldn't make myself clear, here's the code which runs perfectly in python(this logic). but in c, it gives error while sorting.

```
int array[100][2],i,j,n=50,temp[1][2];
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    scanf("%d %d",&list[i][0],&list[i][1]);
}
/*heres's the sorting part which gives error*/

for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){
    for(j=i+1;j<n;j++){
        if(list[j][1]>list[i][1]){
            temp=list[i];
            list[i]=list[j];
            list[j]=temp;
        }
    }
}
```

so what should be the correct approach in C? if you haven't understand my question, please comment!

Comment: You cannot assign array in C. If you want, you can declare a struct. Otherwise, you need to assign the 2 numbers one by one.

Comment: well i wrote the type of temp is int. can that be a problem?

Comment: What type of data is stored int he array? per line i mean

Comment: @nhahtdh, can you please explain your answer in a bit detail..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is clean except for the part that you use to exchange the two-element arrays. There are two ways to fix it:

- Use an alternative representation of the array - `int *array[100]` in which case you'll need to `malloc` and `free` individual elements, or
- Use `memcpy` to exchange two-element arrays in your swap code.
- With only two elements to swap, you can exchange two-element arrays one integer at a time without using `memcpy`

This is one way of doing it:

```
int temp[2];
memcpy(temp, list[i], sizeof(temp));
memcpy(list[i], list[j], sizeof(temp));
memcpy(list[j], temp, sizeof(temp));
```

Comment: well, it runs on my compiler good with 2 warnings... but when i submitted a code using this portion in an online judge under GNU C++ 4.6 it returns compilation error. can you help me with that?

Comment: do i have to include string.h header for this?

Comment: @NasifImtiazOhi Yes, you do need to include `string.h` in order to use the `memcpy` function.